# How can I have two css animations with different frame counts and sizes on the same page

Tags: html, css

I have a page with three css animations. The first two have 2 frames each and are the same size. No problem there. But I added a third animation that has 10 frames and is a different image size. The first two are 104w x 88h. The third is 48w x 64h. When I added the third one, I had to change the @keyframes to account for it and now the first two animations display incorrectly. How can I make this work?

Here's the css for all three animations. Notice that I tried duplicating @keyframes, but all of the animations are using the second one:

```css
#animation1 {
  width: 104px;
  height: 88px;
  background: url('Images/Anim_1.png') left center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: play 1.5s steps(2) infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

#animation2 {
  width: 104px;
  height: 88px;
  background: url('Images/Anim_2.png') left center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: play 1.5s steps(2) infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: -208px;
  }
}

#godmodeanim {
  width: 48px;
  height: 64px;
  background: url('Images/Anim_3.png') left center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: play 6.0s steps(10) infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: -480px;
  }
}
```

```html
<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD colspan=3 style="text-align:center">
      v1.4 images
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      Incorrect Image #1:
      <BR>
      <IMG src="Images/Picture_43.png" alt="Incorrect BJ Panting 1">
    </TD>
    <TD>
      Correct Image #2:
      <BR>
      <IMG src="Images/Picture_84.png" alt="Correct BJ Panting 2">
    </TD>
    <TD>
      Animation:
      <BR>
      <DIV id="animation1"></DIV>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD colspan=3 style="text-align:center">
      v1.1 images
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      Correct Image #1:
      <BR>
      <IMG src="Images/Picture_52.png" alt="Correct BJ Panting 1">
    </TD>
    <TD>
      Correct Image #2:
      <BR>
      <IMG src="Images/Picture_93.png" alt="Correct BJ Panting 2">
    </TD>
    <TD>
      Animation:
      <BR>
      <DIV id="animation2"></DIV>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>

<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD colspan=3 style="text-align:center">
      God Mode
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      Forward:
      <BR>
      <IMG src="Images/GodModeLg.png" alt="BJ Looking Forward">
    </TD>
    <TD>
      Left:
      <BR>
      <IMG src="Images/GodModeLgL.png" alt="BJ Looking Left">
    </TD>
    <TD>
      Right:
      <BR>
      <IMG src="Images/GodModeLgR.png" alt="BJ Looking Right">
    </TD>
    <TD>
      Animation:
      <BR>
      <DIV id="godmodeanim"></DIV>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

I have found no examples anywhere of having multiple @keyframes on the same page.

Comment: I don't know how many times I have to repeat this. HTML is case-INSENSITIVE. The case of the HTML has no bearing on anything. This is my style of coding for decades now. I differentiate between tags and attributes by the case. I will not change the case just because someone else doesn't like it. I would appreciate it if these types of comments could be left out from now on. I want answers to my questions, not critiques of my writing style.

Comment: Can you please add placeholder images so we can test your code? You can use a service like placeholder.com.

Comment: I will try to remember that in the future. I always forget that you can't run the code because you don't have the images. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is no problem in having multiple `@keyframes` in the same page, you just need to give them different names, e.g.

```
  @keyframes play {
    100% {background-position: -208px; }
  }
  @keyframes play2 {
    100% {background-position: -480px; }
  }
  @keyframes play3 {
    100% {background-position: -100px; }
  }
```

I've put together an example below using your code with sample images so you can see it working - the different keyframes are simply moving the image varying amounts to the right (which is what you seem to have been doing), but you can do anything you would normally do in a `@keyframes` sequence:

```css
#animation1 {
    width:104px;
    height:88px;
    background: url('https://placehold.co/104x88/F00/31343C') left center;
    background-size: cover;
    animation: play 1.5s steps(2) infinite;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #animation2 {
    width:104px;
    height:88px;
    background: url('https://placehold.co/104x88/FF0/31343C') left center;
    background-size: cover;
    animation: play2 1.5s steps(2) infinite;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #godmodeanim {
    width:48px;
    height:64px;
    background: url('https://placehold.co/48x64/F0F/31343C') left center;
    background-size: cover;
    animation: play3 6.0s steps(10) infinite;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  @keyframes play {
    100% {background-position: -10px; }
  }
  @keyframes play2 {
    100% {background-position: -80px; }
  }

  @keyframes play3 {
    100% {background-position: -10px; }
  }
```

```html
<TABLE><TR><TD colspan=3 style="text-align:center">
v1.4 images
</TD></TR><TR><TD>
Incorrect Image #1:<BR>
<IMG src="https://placehold.co/100x100/EEE/31343C" alt="Incorrect BJ Panting 1">
</TD>
<TD>
Correct Image #2:<BR>
<IMG src="https://placehold.co/100x100/E1E1E1/31343C" alt="Correct BJ Panting 2">
</TD><TD>
Animation:<BR>
<DIV id="animation1"></DIV>
</TD></TR><TR><TD colspan=3 style="text-align:center">
v1.1 images
</TD></TR><TR><TD>
Correct Image #1:<BR>
<IMG src="https://placehold.co/100x100/DDD/31343C" alt="Correct BJ Panting 1">
</TD><TD>
Correct Image #2:<BR>
<IMG src="https://placehold.co/100x100/D1D1D1/31343C" alt="Correct BJ Panting 2">
</TD><TD>
Animation:<BR>
<DIV id="animation2"></DIV>
</TD></TR></TABLE>

<TABLE><TR><TD colspan=3 style="text-align:center">
God Mode
</TD></TR><TR><TD>
Forward:<BR>
<IMG src="https://placehold.co/100x100/CCC/31343C" alt="BJ Looking Forward">
</TD><TD>
Left:<BR>
<IMG src="https://placehold.co/100x100/C1C1C1/31343C" alt="BJ Looking Left">
</TD><TD>
Right:<BR>
<IMG src="https://placehold.co/100x100/EEE/31343C" alt="BJ Looking Right">
</TD><TD>
Animation:<BR>
<DIV id="godmodeanim"></DIV>
</TD></TR></TABLE>
```

Comment: Thanks. As I was waiting I was searching for an answer on the net. I found the same answer you gave me on W3School when I saw that play was not a function name but an animation name. I tried it and it worked. The first two animations are the same size and number of frames, so I named them play1 and the third I named play2. That fixed it. Thank you for your answer, as it verifies what I found on W3School.

Comment: @WayneCa Glad to help! I wasn't sure when you were referencing `play` 3 times if there was supposed to be a 3rd one or not, but I made a 3rd `@keyframes` anyway to illustrate that you can have as many as you like!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple @keyframes is fine, but you named your @keyframes both play. If you @keyframes are both the same name, you css won't know which one. So it'll just go with the later one. So the code should work if you name them different things. Also, I couldn't view any animations whatsoever on Firefox, they are all just stagnant when I run the code snippet, please fix that.

Comment: Please provide code, since the answer already posted mentions this.

Comment: I know, I didn't notice the first answer because it came on right before I submitted mine.

Comment: I am using Firefox and the animations play in mine, even though the first one was not correct due to the naming issue. I thought play was a function, not a name. Now I know better. It may be the lack of images that caused them not to play in your browser.